# How to project shape inside a mesh

Tags: modeling, add-on

I have a custom shape and i want to project honeycomb shape inside the custom shape. I tried with tissue addon. But did not get good result.

**Tissue addon result**

[image]

[image]

Looking for this result
[image]

Is there any otherway or will tissue addon can fix my issue. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the shrink wrap modifier?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like this ... Knife Project should be enough ... place HoneyComb over Custom Shape, select Custom shape as second switch to edit mode and search for knife Project

[image]

Outline of Custom shape is postpro.